# Data Types VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle

I have a question about data types in Oracle.
For VARCHAR2(123), I know I need to enter 'size' into parenthesis (), like the 123 in my example above. Sometimes there is 'CHAR' or 'BYTE' after the size. For example, VARCHAR2(123 CHAR). I've looked up Oracle official documentation and this is consistent with the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6).

I want to know, when should I enter CHAR/BYTE in ()? When is CHAR/BYTE optional?

I'm asking this question because when I use 'DESCRIBE' command to get a description of a table, some columns do have CHAR/BYTE in the data types, for example:

Column_1   VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)

Other columns, however, don't have CHAR/BYTE:

Column_2   VARCHAR2(5)

Feel free to use DESCRIBE command to test one of your tables. You'll see the same. So it seems there's something special about certain columns that they always have CHAR/BYTE in their data types.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`BYTE` is the default, meaning you can store X number of bytes in the column. If nothing is specified in the `describe` output, then it is `BYTES`.

In the case of double-byte character sets, like UTF8 or AL32UTF8, specifying the maximum number of bytes can result in cases where the column doesn't actually hold as many *characters* as it should. Use the `CHAR` specification when you need to specify the maximum number of characters in the column, with the understanding that this may cause the column to hold more than that number of *bytes*.